# Not able to add new property to mongoose result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I have a userDetail document which has all the details regarding the user.
I have a login document which has a time of the first login which I want to add to the result of the userDetails.
Here is the Code on my Nodejs server application.

```
 Login.findOne({email:req.body.email},(err,loginDetails)=>{

        if(!err){
            if(loginDetails===null){ //user is not already logged in
                    //saving login new details
                let newLogin=new Login();
                newLogin.email=req.body.email;
                newLogin.userType=user.userType;
                newLogin.save((err,loginDetailsAfterSaving)=>{

                    if(err){

                        res.status(500).send(err);
                    }               
                    let token=jsonwebtoken.sign(user.toJSON(),"example1");   
                    res.status(200).json({token:token});
                });

            }
```

for adding 'time' field to the user I tried.

1. `user.time=loginDetailsAfterSaving.time;`
2. `user['time']=loginDetailsAfterSaving.time;`
3. `user.toJSON().time=loginDetailsAfterSaving.time;`

but when i decode the token in my angular app i get result wihout the tine field.
Angular code

```
    let jwtHelper=new JwtHelper();
    let userDetails= jwtHelper.decodeToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    console.log(userDetails);
```

> Problem: it sends the original 'user' object without time field

any help would be great
Thanks

Comment: If you `console.log(loginDetailsAfterSaving.time)` do you get any output?

Comment: @Alan yes i get the correct output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `time` property to the mongoose schema if you want to keep it when the document is converted to JSON.

You could also set the property after calling `toJSON` method

```
const userJson = user.toJSON();
userJson.time = loginDetailsAfterSaving.time;

res.json(userJson);
```